# does spring 3.2 require servlet 3.0 or it works with servlet 2.5

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am using spring 3.2.4 in my application but some of the features are not working properly like @controllerAdvice. I know that it is a feature added in spring 3.2. I am using servlet 2.5.I googled about spring 3.2 and found that

```
The Spring MVC programming model now provides explicit Servlet 3 async support.
```

Kindly tell me does spring 3.2 works with servlet 2.5 or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring 3.2 should work with Servlet 2.5 API.

Only Spring 4.0 requires Serlvet 3.0:

> (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.0.html)
>
> 3 New Features and Enhancements in Spring Framework 4.0)
>
> 3.4 Java EE 6 and 7
>
> Java EE version 6 or above is now considered the baseline for Spring
> Framework 4, with the JPA 2.0 and Servlet 3.0 specifications being of
> particular relevance. In order to remain compatible with Google App
> Engine and older application servers, it is possible to deploy a
> Spring 4 application into a Servlet 2.5 environment. However, Servlet
> 3.0+ is strongly recommended and a prerequisite in Spring’s test and mock packages for test setups in development environments.