# can it run spring 3 on tomcat 9 and java 8?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tomcat9, spring-3

I have found an application that is made with spring 3.2.18.RELEASE and is running on tomcat 9 and java 8.

My knowledge of java and spring is very little, but from what I understand [spring 3 should work with Servlet 2.5 API.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24217865/1989579)

But according to [tomcat page](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), servlet 2.5 is for tomcat 6

Can an application made with spring 3 run in java 8 with tomcat 9 without problems?
What would be the ideal version of java and tomcat for spring 3?

How should the correct versions of java, tomcat and spring be selected?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that will be running ok. I am usign Java 8, Tomcat 8 and Spring 4 and works correctly. And Tomcat 9 also support Java 8.